# mod_rewrite: Convert "/blog/2014/10/08/slug-name/" to "slug-name.html"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The URL convention for the blog I'm working on is changing from "/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/post-name/" to just "post-name.html".

To retain backward compatbility, I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to strip the "/blog/YYY/MM/DD/", remove trailing /, and add ".html".

I'm not great with regex or mod_rewrite.  (Even if this "worked", I'd still question if it is the best way.)

So here's where I am at:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/([\w\-]+)/?$ /$1.html
```

Doesn't seem to be working, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Do I have the regex wrong? the rule written wrong? or totally missing something else?  I've used a tool called Patterns to work with the regex, but still not confident I have it right.

**Example**:

```
/blog/2014/10/08/whatever-was-here/
```

should rewrite to

```
whatever-was-here.html
```

Comment: you've got `/$1`, so you'd actually be requesting `/whatever-was-here.html`. So... HOW is this not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194352/htaccess-redirect-folder)

Comment: @MarcB "Not working" was that the "redirect" never occurred and apache gave no error.  Of course, I finally realized (while typing this) I never told apache to redirect...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, spent too much time overthinking this one.  The rule was correct, I forgot to add the flags...  [R=301,L]